# particular id selector can not margin through the css setting

Tags: html, css

### HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="content-row">
      <div class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span4" id="home-logo">
            <img src="img/layout/logo.png" id="logo">
            
                  <ul id="subnav">
                        <!-- Loaded via AJAX -->
                  </ul>
            
          </div><!-- ./span4 -->
          <div class="span8" id="home-copy">
            <p id="home-p">
                Foxcode is an investment and merchant banking Firm which advises and invests in small to mid-market companies and projects globally.
            </p>
          </div><!-- ./span8 -->
        </div><!-- ./row-fluid -->
      </div><!-- span12 -->
    </div><!-- ./row-fluid -->
```

I try to set `#subnav{margin-left: }`  or `#subnav li{margin-left: }` to control the element position so it goes to the right a little bit, but nothing happens when I try to.

### Concerned element

```
<ul id="subnav">
    <!-- Loaded via AJAX -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Set your li tags manualy, Perocat answer works. Maybe your ajax script is not working right.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to your CSS:

```
#subnav{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mthsH/)

Comment: #subnav {
  float:right;
  margin-top: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
i already havet this css

Comment: THE ISSUE GOT FIXED!! THANK YOU